# Euclidean Algorithm / GCD in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write the Euclidean Algorithm in Python. It's to find the GCD of two really large numbers. The formula is a = bq + r where a and b are your two numbers, q is the number of times b divides a evenly, and r is the remainder.

I can write the code to find that, however if it the original numbers don't produce a remainder (r) of zero then the algorithm goes to step 2 => b = rx + y. (same as the first step but simply subbing b for a, and r for b) the two steps repeat until r divides both a and b evenly.

This is my code, I haven't yet figured out how to do the subbing of values and create a loop until the GCD is found.

```
a = int(input("What's the first number? "))
b = int(input("What's the second number? ")) 
r = int(a - (b)*int(a/b))

if r == 0:
  print("The GCD of the two choosen numbers is " + str(b))

elif r != 0:
  return b and r
  (b == a) and (r == b)

print("The GCD of the two numbers is " + str(r))
```

Comment: Hint - `a - b*(a//b)` is the same as `a % b`.

Comment: This should help you get started: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm

Answer (score 8):

```
a = int(input("What's the first number? "))
b = int(input("What's the second number? ")) 
r=a%b
while r:
    a=b
    b=r
    r=a%b
print('GCD is:', b)
```

or use `break` in loop:

```
a = int(input("What's the first number? "))
b = int(input("What's the second number? ")) 
while 1:
    r=a%b
    if not r:
        break
    a=b
    b=r
print('GCD is:', b)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think that's the shortest solution:

```py
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
a = int(input("Enter No.1"))

b = int(input("Enter No.2"))

r = a%b

q = int(a/b)

while(r!=0):

    a = b

    b = r

    q = int(a/b)

    r = a - (b * q)


print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old post but here it is:

```
def GCD(x , y):
    """This is used to calculate the GCD of the given two numbers.
    You remember the farm land problem where we need to find the 
    largest , equal size , square plots of a given plot?"""
    if y == 0:
        return x
    r = int(x % y)
    return GCD(y , r)
```

Taken from Algorithms 4th edition.

Note: if your numbers are REALLY REALLY large then try to increase the recursion limit by:

```
import sys
sys.seterecursionlimit("your new limit")
```

but be very very careful with it. I was able to fill my 12GB RAM and cause a freeze quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's one missing important condition for Euclidean Algorithm to work, which is a >= b > 0. So may I suggest this code I just made (quite long cuz I haven't viewed prev answers before building it haha.

```
def gcd(int1: int, int2: int):
# I used a recursive algorithm
# Condition: a>=b>0
if int1 < int2:
    a = int2
    b = int1
else:
    a = int1
    b = int2

if a % b == 0:
    return b
else:
    r = a % b
    gcd(b, r)
    return r
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a question like this in my math class. The code I wrote was:

```
def EuclideanAlg(a,b):
    # switches the value of a and b if a is less than b
    if a <= b - 1:
        temp = a
        a = b
        b = temp
    # takes the remainder after a is divided by b
    r = a % b
    # iterates infinitely
    while True:
        # if a is divisible by b, b is the gcd of a,b
        if r == 0:
            return b
            break
        # a becomes the current value of b and b becomes the current value of r
        else:
            temp = r
            r = b % r
            b = temp
```